# Tela para relacionar visualmente itens entre duas colunas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela em HTML, CSS e JQuery para relacionar duas colunas: uma com os lançamentos de um extrato bancário e a outra com o tipo de lançamento, assim eu clico em um lançamento na primeira coluna e depois no tipo dele na coluna do meio, jogando para uma terceira coluna tudo o que já listei daquele tipo.

Alguém conhece algum modelo pronto ou diferente que eu possa adaptar, para ter noção do melhor funcionamento?

Comment: Pesquise por DataTables.

Comment: Inclua o que você já tentou

Comment: @Natan me confirma se é oque entendi: vou dar um exemplo, coluna 1(lancamentos): 'a-> dep. env. dinheiro R$ 50,00', coluna 2(tipo): '1-> deposito dinheiro, 2-> pagamento boleto, 3-> saque', coluna 3(que titulo seria?): '', ai quando eu clico no lançamento 'a' da coluna 1 e clico no tipo 1 da coluna tipo, a coluna 3 recebe esse tipo? e some o tipo selecionado da coluna 2? é isso que você precisa? se puder dar exemplo um print da tela facilita o entendimento.